# Import scenarios of test cases in Enterprise Architect

Tags: import, enterprise-architect

Is there an easy way to import scenarios of test cases in Enterprise Architect? Of course it is possible to import stuff from CSV but this is limited to a limited number of available fields. For instance the GUID, Phase, Stereotype and Author.

The Scenarios are only available at the Test Case specific blocks and inside I want to be able to import the Action and Uses for every step. The number of steps can also vary from 3 to more.

Comment: Where are your test cases normally stored (qtest, jira, testRail...)  ? Maybe there is something that can do that for you.. Or what fields do you need to import ? What results would you like for the import ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unfortunately there is no *easy* way.

There is however the hard way. You can use the API of EA to create elements. I did this in the past using VBA in Excel in my [Excel Importer](http://bellekens.com/2015/10/24/simple-vba-excel-to-ea-importer-v4/)

You could use that as a starting point for the import of scenarios.